# How to view previous wildfly server.log in openshift environment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, wildfly-10, openshift-3, openshift-online

Trying to identify the cause of restart of the `wildfly` application in a `openshift POD`:

- `POD Describe` shows no restart for the POD.
- `oc logs xxx --previous` does not find any entry.
- `Wildfly log directory` holds entry for the current `server.log`.

I remember something about using `Kibana` to see old logs.

**What are the options to quickly see the old logs for `wildfly` running under `openshift`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oc logs --previous` depends on container logs which is managed by container runtime(such as docker). If the pod(container) was restarted due to unnormal states, container logs are remained. At that case, `oc logs --previous` shows you old logs. As I see, the previous logs are not remained at the moment.

How about looking for the previous logs using `Pod name`, `Project` and `Timestamp` ?

Comment: I used oc logs with --since-time option but did not see any extra log content for wildfly. It seems the oc logs scope is current POD only and the wildfly crashed during the previous POD. I need to look into the wildfly server.log at the crash time.

Comment: Logs are limited to pods. To preserve the logs, you need to attach PVC and change the log location to that.